# Detect duplicates without exposing underlying data

Tags: encryption, hash, sha, hmac, scrypt

We have a scenario where we need to prevent two users from using the same identifier. The identifier is sensitive (e.g. a social security number), so we do not want to store it in our DB. We just want to store some sort of hash that allows us to prevent subsequent users from using it again. And we want to do it securely, so that in the event that the database ever leaked, an attacker could not figure out the original values.

Is it possible to do securely? What is the recommended way?

Based on some research, it seems like a HMAC might work. If that's the case, what's the recommended algorithm? Should it be something slow (like scrypt with a fixed key salt), so that if the key is ever exposed, it's still difficult to uncover the values? Or is there no protection against that?

Comment: scrypt is not a HMAC, scrypt is a Key-Derivation Function. A KDF is just fine for these purposes. I recommend Argon2id.

Comment: How much "entropy" does your identifier have?  For instance, if it is a social security number, then even a naive calculation suggests the total amount of entropy is low (9 digits = 1 billion possibilities), although actually entropy is much less than that even.  As a result, hashing can be very ineffective, because brute-forcing is relatively easy, and extra care is needed.  Is it actually a SSN, or is that just an example you picked?

Comment: @MechMK1 so you would use Argon2id with a fixed salt?

Comment: @ConorMancone Yes, it is a SSN, so the entropy is low.

Comment: @PeterWatts Why a fixed salt? That would make things worse. Argon2id has the ability to use a key, just like a HMAC would. Use a unique and sufficiently random salt, in combination with a long, sufficiently random key.

Comment: @MechMK1, I assume it's because the use case requires comparing equality.

Comment: @timuzhti exactly

Comment: Ah, so to be clear, you want to know if the identifier is used *anywhere* in your system?  For typical password use-cases you just need to know if a particular user used a given password, so having a random salt per-user is fine and safer.  However, if you need to compare a given identifier against *all other* identifiers in your system, then indeed a random salt won't work.  In that case you really just don't want a salt (although it may be impossible to skip, in which case a fixed salt would be the thing-to-do).

Comment: @PeterWatts The salt must be unique per-entry. After a salt has been generated, it stays fixed, else the comparison would fail. But when you say "fixed salt", it seemed to me as if you wanted one salt for everything. This would be bad.

Comment: @MechMK1 in this case I think he **would** need one salt for everything. I'm not quite convinced that would make this impossible, but certainly extra care is needed in other ways

Comment: @ConorMancone If the data is already associated with the user in some way, then no. But if he doesn't know and just wants to know if there are any collisions, that's a different story.

Answer (score 10):

I think you're not too far from a possible solution (aka using a modern KDF and effectively treating this like a password).  However, there are some more considerations (which were already mentioned in comments):

1. SSNs have very low entropy, which means that brute-force is an especially easy attack
2. Since you need to find if the SSN has been used anywhere, you basically have to operate without a salt, which also makes brute-forcing **substantially** easier.

The combination of 1 & 2 would make a KDF a bad idea, even though it is your only option.  As a result, finding a different **business** solution may be in order.  However, I think there are a few steps you can take to mitigate the risk if SSN matching is an absolute requirement:

1. Make sure and use a large "pepper".  Peppers are less commonly used with passwords, so in case you aren't familiar: using a pepper basically means adding a large, constant, random string to the SSN before hashing which is not stored in the database.  In this case I would use an especially long pepper.  So in practice, this means that you create a 256 bit key **that is not stored in the database or codebase** but which is added to the SSN before hashing it.  You would store it in an environment variable in your production server, or in your CD pipeline, so it is not readily accessible to developers (since they are sometimes the attacker, unfortunately).  The reason for this is that if your database leaks but the attacker doesn't have the pepper, then they cannot bruteforce the SSNs (because bruteforcing the SSN would basically require first bruteforcing your 256 bit key, which is impossible).
2. Use a very large cost function.  All modern KDFs have a configurable cost function, that increases the time it takes to buid the hash (therefore making brute force harder).  For something like this I'd set an even-higher-than-usual cost function.  I'd probably tune it so that your systems take 1-2 seconds to hash the SSN+pepper.  Go even higher if your users can tolerate the wait!  This won't fix your bruteforce issue, but it will help.
3. Anonymize these hashed SSNs!  Basically, store them in a table by themselves with no way to associate them with any other data in the system (i.e. don't assign an autoincrementing id to this table or an entry time, since those might correlate with other tables).  Have one table with just one column that is for this purpose and this purpose only.  While the SSN alone is still personal information, it is much less dangerous to your users if it is leaked by itself without **any** further information.  Having a table with just the hashed SSNs will still allow you to verify if an SSN has been entered before, so your overall goal can still be accomplished.

So again, your best bet might simply be to find a completely different way to do this without using SSNs.  However, if this is an absolute business requirement, then the above steps can go a long way to securing your customer's personal data.  Still, I would also check with regulatory requirements for your industry to make sure that you abide by all applicable rules.

Comment: Ah! I had not considered that 3rd step. While it would be nice to know which user was associated with the re-used identifier, it's not critical, and seems like a reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: The problem with storing the SSN with no identifying information is that it provides no recourse in the case of a collision. A hacker could (for example) enroll thousands of random SSNs in an application DoS attack, denying legitimate users the ability to use their own SSN if they are unfortunate enough to collide.

Comment: Maybe a hardware security module can be used to store the pepper, if a suitable one can be found, to make it even harder to steal.